# Generic extension method parameter restrictions

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I am creating an extension method to `IQueryable` for automapper to pass in a standard parameter. Though this code below works, it seems a bit redundant to have to specify the `TSource` type when invoking this method (as in below invocation code)....i.e. having to specify `<Item,` in the method call when it already knows the type of `entityQuery` is `Item`.

I'm not an expert in generics, but wondering if there is a way to remove this redundancy during invocation but still qualify the `TSource` as needing to conform to interface `IAuditStampsViewModel`?

**Invocation**

```
public IQueryable<ItemViewModel> ConvertClassToViewModel(IQueryable<Item> entityQuery)
{
    return entityQuery.ProjectToPassUserTimeOffset<Item, ItemViewModel>();
}
```

**Extension Method definition**

```
public static class AutoMapperExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TDestination> ProjectToPassUserTimeOffset<TSource, TDestination>(this IQueryable<TSource> entityQuery)
        where TSource : class, IAuditStampsViewModel, new()
    {
        return entityQuery.ProjectTo<TDestination>(
            new { intMinutesOffset = TimeUtilities.UserTimeZoneUTCOffsetMinutes() }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd have to add an argument of the `TDestinatino` type so that it can also infer it as it's currently all or nothing for inferring generic types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just constrain on `IAuditStampsViewModel`? Then you could write:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TDestination> ProjectToPassUserTimeOffset<TDestination>(this IQueryable<IAuditStampsViewModel> entityQuery)
    {
        return entityQuery.ProjectTo<TDestination>(new {intMinutesOffset=TimeUtilities.UserTimeZoneUTCOffsetMinutes()});
    }
}
```

The caller would be:

```
public IQueryable<ItemViewModel> ConvertClassToViewModel(IQueryable<Item> entityQuery)
{
    return entityQuery.ProjectToPassUserTimeOffset<ItemViewModel>();
}
```